# TWRP for new 2020 Samsung device

Tags: samsung, twrp

I wanted to buy a new phone, but one that I could install TWRP on. I searched and found that the Galaxy A01 CORE is cheap and good and I almost bought it.  I tried to search for TWRP for the device unsuccessfully.

I have not found **any guide or website that explains how to** install TWRP on this device. Is it because it's new and only came out on 6/8/20?

The question is basically about new phones and TWRP, since the phone came out it has been about 4 months, how long does it take until a version of TWRP is released that is suitable for the phone? If I want a phone with TWRP I will always have to buy an old one? Because new phones are always released every year, and the problem is that **stores are no longer selling phones from 2019**, so what can be done?

Is there some way to install TWRP on Galaxy A01 Core?

Comment: for this device you probably won't get source code. but you can port TWRP recovery from another MT6739 device (BLU Vivo ONE or
K-touch i9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- TWRP is not released by OEMs. It is developed independently by volunteers *after* the device is marketed and it's kernel and ROM sources are released  (they are legally obliged under GPLv2.0) .
- Not all devices have TWRP because they are not suitable for development for technical reasons like bootloader can't be unlocked, SoC not suitable, OEM releasing source late etc. Also, developers make TWRP for devices that are popular and suitable for development. OEMs at times give out free devices to developers to make their devices popular.
- If you are keen on buying a device that has TWRP support, keep a tab on the device forums on [XDA](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.xda-developers.com/&ved=2ahUKEwim-vzBrKLtAhVDeX0KHRQ_BVQQFjAAegQIBhAD&usg=AOvVaw23CoqPUXdtcnWKJlb6JSFe)
  and based on the TWRP /kernel /ROM support from developer community, take a decision to buy or not.
- This site doesn't give buying recommendations. If you can't find the device in stores, look for alternatives like on line sites etc. Google is your friend.
- Or else, learn how to develop (this site doesn't support questions on that) and make your own TWRP. Note that TWRP is specific to the device & device variant (Samsung makes several variants for the same model) and you *can't* use TWRP meant for some other device, irrespective of similarities in devices.

Comment: Ty man! You know how I can find out if the OEM released the source version of my device or is it late?

Comment: Again your best bet would be device forums on XDA and some other sites like Android authority etc. I am not keeping track of Samsung devices

Comment: Even though this site does not give recommendations for specific phones, maybe you know which company is usually easier to put TWRP on? Because I heard that Samsung and Google for example have an open bootloader, so you do not need to unlock bootloader?

Comment: For all modern devices, you need to unlock bootloader to root your device and install TWRP.. You can start off by reading tag wiki of [rooting](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info), [bootloader](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bootloader/info), [Unlocking](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bootloader-lock/info) to get basic understanding //Google devices need to be unlocked //Not sure about Samsung devices //Just because they can be unlocked, does not mean you have TWRP

Comment: My current device is Pixel 4a which can be unlocked and rooted but no TWRP //Read the tag wiki of TWRP (you tagged that to question) and decide what exactly you want, why, your budget and look for popular devices //Welcome to Android Enthusiasts SE :)